# Formatting numbers with unit symbols "k" and "m"

Tags: vbscript, number-formatting

In VBScript I'm looking for a function that will return the numbers in the format 1000s or if 1000,000 or greater in millions as follows:

```
x = 100,000 then return 100k
y = 500,000 then return 500k
z = 5,000,000 then return 5m
q = 25,000,000 then return 25m
```

Where x, y, z, q are integers.

Comment: in pseudo code:
if(x>1000000)
return x/1000000 + "m"
else if(x>1000)
return x/1000 + "k"
^ any problem with writing a function that does this or are you just looking for specific VB syntax your confused about... or looking for a utility method that does some more generic formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@van: Working example --

```
Option Explicit

Function NumFormat(ByRef iNumber, ByRef blnFixed)
    Dim sNumber

    If iNumber >= 1000000 Then
        If NOT blnFixed Then
            sNumber = (iNumber / 1000000) & "m"
        Else
            sNumber = Fix(iNumber / 1000000) & "m"
        End If
    ElseIf iNumber >= 100000 Then
        If NOT blnFixed Then
            sNumber = (iNumber / 1000) & "k"
        Else
            sNumber = Fix(iNumber / 1000) & "k"
        End If
    ElseIf iNumber >= 10000 Then
        If NOT blnFixed Then
            sNumber = (iNumber / 1000) & "k"
        Else
            sNumber = Fix(iNumber / 1000) & "k"
        End If
    ElseIf iNumber >= 1000 Then
        If NOT blnFixed Then
            sNumber = (iNumber / 1000) & "k"
        Else
            sNumber = Fix(iNumber / 1000) & "k"
        End If
    End If

    NumFormat = sNumber
End Function

Response.Write NumFormat(56120000, True) & "<br>"
Response.Write NumFormat(25050000, False) & "<br>"
Response.Write NumFormat(255000, False) & "<br>"
Response.Write NumFormat(9009, True) & "<br>"
Response.Write NumFormat(3000, False) & "<br>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Public Function convertAmount(a)
    a = CStr(a)
    Dim re : Set re = new RegExp

    ' Replace millions
    re.Pattern ="(,\d{3}){2}$"
    a = re.replace(a, "m")
    ' Replace kilo's
    re.Pattern =",\d{3}$"
    a = re.replace(a, "k")

    convertAmount = a
End Function

' Testcode
MsgBox convertAmount("1,234,567")
```

It could be it wouldn't work for integers, because I never have seen integers with thousand separator formatting. Just place a question mark in the regular expressions behind the comma, and it will also work for numbers without thousand separators. Like:
`"(,?\d{3}){2}$"` and `",?\d{3}$"`

Limitations: No rounding, only trunking of the results